# How can I have center the selected tab with XLPagerTabStrip?

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I want to have a viewpager having 5 tabs. Max. 3 should be visible at a time, having equal widths and it should center the selected tab. 
It would be like Fotmob's app screen.

The layout would be like this:

```
Yesterday | Live| Today | Tomorrow | Day after Tomorrow
```

How can I achieve this with `XLPagerTabStrip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `buttonBarLeftContentInset` and `buttonBarRightContentInset` in `settings.style` to a high value, that will center the selected item.

```
settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 9999
settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 9999
```

Sadly, there is no easy way to set up the maximum visibility count with `XLPagerTabStrip`. You can try to set different values (considering the screen/font size) for `settings.style.buttonBarMinimumInteritemSpacing`.

Comment: Thanks! its worked. but now how can i ensure that only 3 tabs will be visible on screen or can i give equal width to the tabs

Comment: +1 Thanks man! you rock `settings.style.buttonBarMinimumInteritemSpacing` works for me. 
Could you do me a favour, i have another question on SO can you help me on that.